# Why does JSON.parse work on 1 element arrays?

Tags: javascript, json

The documentation seems to say that `JSON.parse` should only work on strings:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

However, it appears that it works on 1-length array integer values:

```js
-> JSON.parse([123])
<- 123
-> JSON.parse(["[123]"])
<- [123]
```

However, if there's more than one value, it breaks:

```js
-> JSON.parse([123, 456])
<- VM439:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

Or a single string value:

```
-> JSON.parse(['string'])
<- VM586:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

Does anyone know why it behaves this way?

Comment: JavaScript automatically converts arrays to strings by effectively doing `array.join(',')`

Comment: All built-in functions that require a string argument automatically convert the argument to a string.

Comment: @PeterB, well, I hadn't written it, but this was the code I was working with:

    try {
            operand = JSON.parse(operand);
          } catch (e) { /* */ }

And operand could sometimes be an array, and sometimes a string.

Comment: @Barmar Haha, so I could do `JSON.parse(['{"one": 1', '"two": 2', '"three": 3}'])`, makes sense now, threw me off when I was trying to debug this logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the param is likely being coerced to a string.

`[123] + ''` results in `'123'`, and `JSON.parse('123')` results in `123`.

`[123, 4] + ''` results in `'123,4'`, and `JSON.parse('123,4')` results in a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 2):

It attempts to treat the array as a string.

```js
console.log([123].toString()); // Valid JSON
console.log([123, 456].toString()); // Not valid JSON
console.log(['string'].toString()); // Not valid JSON
```